# How do I determine the build number of Microsoft Office C2R?

Tags: c#, vba, ms-office

On a system with Office Click-To-Run (Office 2016 Retail or Office 365), how do I (programmatically) determine the build number?

**Background:** Some features are [only available in newer builds](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-s-new-in-Office-365-95c8d81d-08ba-42c1-914f-bca4603e1426), and I want to check whether the installed version of Office is "new enough" for the feature I want to use and advise the user to upgrate if it isn't.

**Note:** I know that I could probably poke around the registry and look for something that *looks like* the build number (e.g. `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration\(Client)VersionToReport`), but I'd prefer an "officially supported" solution.

Solutions in VBA or any of the .NET languages (or even WMI + the scripting language of your choice) are fine for me.

Comment: `Application.Build` in VBA depending on how detailed you need it to be.

Comment: @Rory: Great, this is exactly what I was looking for! But why did you write your answer in a comment?

Comment: I wasn't sure how detailed a level you needed?

Comment: @Rory: Build number should be detailed enough to determine whether a feature is available or not, so that's perfect for my purposes. Feel free to copy your comment to the answer box, so that it can collect upvotes and a check mark. :-)

Comment: Will do - wasn't sure if you needed the full number or just the major build part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Application.Build` in VBA depending on how detailed you need it to be.